# Various MongoDB error after upgrade mongo server version to 3.6

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Few months back I have upgraded to mongo db verstion to 3.6 and all node js driver to latest version. After that it is start generating following errors at random interval:

1. MongoError: server is closed at Server.query
2. MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended at applySession
3. MongoError: connection pool closed at ConnectionPool.close
4. MongoError: pool destroyed at Pool.write

I am also not able to simulate these error as it worked most of the time and generate error once in a couple of weeks or once in a month.

Here is my mongo controller code:

```js
function controller(environmentConfig) {
    var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        db,

        isAlreadyConnected = function () {
            var isConnected = !!(db && db.topology.isConnected());
            return isConnected;
        },

        connectFunction = function (callback) {
            var cb = callback || function() {};
            if(isAlreadyConnected()) {
                return cb(db);
            }
            var options = {
                server: {
                    socketOptions: {
                        connectTimeoutMS: 300000,
                        socketTimeoutMS: 300000,
                        keepAlive: 300000,
                    },
                    mongos: {
                        connectTimeoutMS: 300000,
                        socketTimeoutMS: 300000,
                        keepAlive: 300000,
                    }
                }
            };

            mongo.connect(environmentConfig.databaseConnectionString, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, options, function(connectionErr, newClient) {
                // one final check
                if(isAlreadyConnected()) {
                    // we do have a connection, so close this one
                    db.topology.close();
                } else {
                    console.log('Mongo: now connected');
                    db = newClient.db(newClient.s.options.dbName);
                }
                return cb(db);
            });
        };

    return {
        connect: connectFunction,
        getDb: function (callback) {
            var cb = callback || function() {};

            if(!isAlreadyConnected()) {
                connectFunction(function(client) {
                    return cb(client);
                });

                return;
            }
            return cb(db);
        }
    }
}
module.exports = controller;
```